# Showing that $A=\lambda I +N$ for some nilpotent matrix $N$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Assume that $A\in \mathbb M^{n\times n}(F)$ for some field $F$ such that the only eigenvalue of $A$ in any extension of $F$ is $\lambda$.

I want to show that there is some nilpotent matrix $N$ so that $A=\lambda I +N$.

I am pretty lost. I can see that the Jordan form of $A$ will have $\lambda$ along its diagonal. But I am not sure how this helps.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Put $N=A-\lambda I$. If $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $N$, what is $\mu$ ? and what is the characteristic polynomial of $N$ ?

Comment: @Kelenner As there is only one eigenvalue, we'll have $\dim G_\lambda=\dim \ker (A-\lambda I)^n=n$ where $G_\lambda$ denotes the generalized eigenspace associated with $\lambda$. So $N^n=0$, as desired. Right?

Comment: Yes, you can say in an equivalent way that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $P(X)=(X-\lambda)^n$ (or that the characteristic polynomial of $N=A-\lambda I$ is $X^n$) and use Cayley-Hamilton 's theorem.

Comment: Ok, but how exactly do we know that $c_N(X)=X^n$?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial $Q$ of $N$  is a monic polynomial of degree $n$, and all the zeros of $Q$ are eigenvalues of $N$, hence $0$. So $Q(X)=X^n$

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

$A = STS^{-1}$, where  $T $ is upper-triangular,  wth only $\lambda $ on the diagonal.  So $T=\lambda I + K $, where $ K $ is nilpotent.  Then $A = S(\lambda I + K)S^{-1} = S\lambda I S^{-1} + SKS^{-1} = \lambda I + SKS^{-1}$.  Since $K $ is nilpotent, it can be easily shown that  $N=SKS^{-1}$ is nilpotent as well.